# Applescript calling shell command

Tags: applescript

I have tried many things but it doesn't seems that I can get this to work. I'm trying to execute the following in an applescript and hitting all kinds of issues. Script runs fine from the shell directly. Unfortunately all the single/double quotes are required to execute the shell command.

```
do shell script "/users/username/Downloads/ofexport2-master-2/bin/of2 -ti 'available && defer.is("today")'  -F -p -o /users/username/Desktop/myFile.txt"
```

Comment: what errors/issues do you get?

Comment: try to mask the quotation marks with backslashes: \"today\"

Answer (score 0):

Because applescript uses " marks to know where to start and stop for certain commands, because you used " in the actual command its gonna get confused where to stop and start so, where "today", etc.. are, use \", this will tell applescript that these quotes are part of the text, try this:

```
do shell script "/users/username/Downloads/ofexport2-master-2/bin/of2 -ti 'available && defer.is(\"today\")'  -F -p -o /users/username/Desktop/myFile.txt"
```